# Arbitrary rating field

Tags: rating

I need a field that will allow content editors to enter a rating while editing a node, with the options 'yes', 'no', 'maybe' and 'unknown'. I then want to be able to display those ratings in a view, as images (tick, cross, fence, ?). I need to be able to have more than one on each node.

I can't do this with the [rate module](https://drupal.org/project/rate), because it doesn't do fields (there is [a rate field issue](https://drupal.org/node/1244858), but it's not moving very fast). Fivestar only does five-star ratings, so that's out.

Optionally, I would also like to be able to give each result a numerical value, so that I can do calculations across fields (e.g. median).

Are there any options out there that can do this kind of rating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need a field that will allow content editors to enter a rating while editing a node...

You could use Drupal's built in Field API to do this. Given that a node will already be in edit mode while being rated, you wont need any additional add-on modules.

[image: Add field to content type dialog]

If you use the integer type, calculations should be simple.  You can override the text like this:

[image]

To add the images next to each item, you could use CSS.  Each element should have the necessary classes to theme them as required.